# How to encourage on hold questions to be improved by the asker?

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions

This is an issue that is bugging me, a lot of the on hold questions can be improved, yet I feel like most people don't get the idea that their questions will be reopened once they are improved. I think it's our fault we are not conveying this idea correctly. And they feel like it won't be opened, so often they vanish from the site afterwards. One example is [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69114/gameobjects-gamecomponents-and-circular-dependencies), I think it can be considerably improved but it's hard for us to edit it. So can we encourage the asker to edit his question so it can be reopened. I feel like we are not explaining that On Hold doesn't mean closed and can be improved clearly.

Comment: Why should the author wait until the reopen-process is finished when they can just delete the old question and ask a new one? The new question will be open immediately and won't have a stigma from a lengthy this-should-be-closed-because discussion and often also some down-votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Except in situations where questions are closed because we don't have enough information, feel free to edit the question to fit with the rules of the site. Be bold. The outcomes from this are:

- We now have a question that can be answered, thus improving the site.

OR

- The user comes back and fixes the question you edited to mean what they really wanted, thus starting the process of them editing the question to fit.

Otherwise, the only way to encourage them is to suggest they edit the question via a comment. Point out what should be changed and suggest they change it.